# Firefox new-bookmark dialogue: increase (or disable) the timeout after which it will auto-confirm

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, delay, dialog

When I press control-D in Firefox on an un-bookmarked page, a dialogue opens, letting me pick a title and other options for the bookmark to be created. However, if it takes me longer than 3.5 seconds, for example because I need to think about the title, or about which folder to store it in, or if I am in doubt whether to save it at all, **the dialogue automatically closes and the bookmark is created**.

This peculiar behaviour seems strange to me, automatically changing things which are stored permanently, and which can be important.

Is there a way to **turn off** this behaviour, or at least **increase the delay**? Based on [this](https://www.camp-firefox.de/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1108858&sid=954130e9ce3246cc97b9b5738f68a985#p1108858) suggestion, I have created a file `NewBookmarkDialogueDelay.js` in the folder `D:\`(my user)`\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`(my profile)`\chrome`, containing the following code:

```
(function() {
  if (window.StarUI) {
    const delay = 60;
    StarUI._autoCloseTimeout = delay * 1000;
  }
})();
```

But that did nothing. How can this be accomplished? I'm using Firefox 66.0.3 in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is by design, unfortunately,
so is built-into the Firefox code.

There was a bug-report opened for it in 2016:
[Bug 1290011 : Prevent the "New Bookmark" menu from timing out and creating the bookmark in a default location](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1290011),
which terminated with the promise by the developer to undo this "feature".
Apparently the fix was lost.

A workaround that worked for me is to click immediately inside the dialog's field.
Once the cursor is displayed inside, the dialog stayed open indefinitely for me.
It's even enough to bring the cursor over the dialog for it to stay open.

Comment: Gosh, how weird. Thanks for the information. If there is really no way to fix this from within Firefox, I'll make an Autohotkey script to fix it (e.g. by automatically moving the mouse over the dialogue for a split second whenever the bookmark dialogue appears).

Comment: You're right : It's enough that the cursor hovers over the dialog, no click required.

Comment: I will! But I'll wait a while first, in case someone else happens to have new/other info.

Comment: ...and, if you think my question was valid, you might consider voting for it.